# PHP Rest API Structure

Tags: php, api, rest

Im new to PHP, im building out a Rest Api for a mobile app. There are alot of different ways people implement a Rest API from what ive seen in Youtube and web searches. I have built quite a bit of the api and im starting to see the cracks in the structure of the application specifically around GET, POST, PUT and DELETE. Every call i have is POST because i always need a method name. Sample below (this is one of the smaller ones)

What i need to know specifically is, show each function require its own php file? Seems odd to me because there would be alot of duplicated code but im thinking now that this would aid me in using the correct http methods.

Thanks for looking :)

`

```
<?php

// headers
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Content-Type: application/json');

include_once ("../../config/Database.php");
include_once ("../../config/Mailer.php");
include_once ("../../config/CustomResponseHandler.php");
include_once ("../../models/AdCampaign.php");

$database      = new Database();
$db            = $database->connect();
$adCampaign    = new AdCampaign($db);

$POST = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);

switch($POST["method"])
{
    case "DeleteAdCampaign":
        echo $adCampaign->DeleteAdCampaign($POST["adcampaignid"]);
        break;
    case "UpdateAdCampaign":
        echo $adCampaign->UpdateAdCampaign($POST["storeid"], $POST["adcampaignid"], $POST["description"], $POST["imageurl"], 
                                           $POST["b64image"], $POST["mimetype"]);
        break;
    case "CreateAdCampaign":
        echo $adCampaign->CreateAdCampaign($POST["storeid"], $POST["description"], $POST["validfrom"], $POST["validto"], 
                                           $POST["b64image"], $POST["mimetype"]);
        break;
    case "GetStoreAdCampaigns":
        echo $adCampaign->GetStoreAdCampaigns($POST["storeid"]);
        break;
    case "GetAllAdCampaigns":
        echo $adCampaign->GetAllAdCampaigns();
        break;
     
    default:
        $response = new CustomResponseHandler();
        $response->returnErrorResponse('','No method found');
        break;
}


?>
```

`

looking for advice, code works fine but may be a poor approach

Comment: in the code above you can see multiple methods which require input parameters but GetAllAdCampaigns doesn't. However i must always POST json to include the method name for the switch statement.

Comment: Typically people use frameworks that use a router to handle this for you. Would recommend that if you're just starting out.

Comment: You also can try this skeleton: https://github.com/rhubenni/tskel-api